# Why Android Threading work and async not work

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

i got a list that contain A, B and C, and i send it via WCF to aSp.NET.
when i use async task i got A, C and C, but when i use threading it work well.

here is my code:

```
case R.id.btn_Reception:
            {               
                for(Pers_Ordre p : ListOrdres){              
                    dbcon.open();   

                    p.setLe_Statut("1");
                    p.setLe_Camion(sharePref_Camion.getString("CammionSetting",""));

                    ordreItem = p;  

                    dbcon.createItmes(p);                   
                    dbcon.close(); 

                    // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread

                    // new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://myseite/Service.svc/FA/SaveData");   

                      new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {

                                        }
                                    });                     

                                 POST("http://myseite/Service.svc/FA/SaveData", ordreItem);

                            }
                          }).start(); 
                }   

                  ListOrdres.clear(); 
                  m_adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, ListOrdres);
                  m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  lv_Ordre.setAdapter(m_adapter);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Rec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
```

as you can see i comented the async task.

**EDITED**

Here is my async code:

```
private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {           
                 return POST(urls[0],ordreItem);            
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.isEmpty())result ="Oke";
        //else result = "Doublons";
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("ERR_WCF", result);
   }
}

public static String POST(String url, Pers_Ordre  TheOrdre){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();        

         jsonObject.accumulate("CodeClient", TheOrdre.getLe_CodeClient());
         jsonObject.accumulate("CodeDest", TheOrdre.getLe_CodeDest());
         jsonObject.accumulate("NoOrdre", TheOrdre.getLe_NoOrdre());
         jsonObject.accumulate("LeDate", TheOrdre.getLe_Date());
         jsonObject.accumulate("LeGPS", TheOrdre.getLe_GPS());            
         jsonObject.accumulate("LeStatut", TheOrdre.getLe_Statut());
         jsonObject.accumulate("LeCamion", TheOrdre.getLe_Camion());
         jsonObject.accumulate("LeOrdrePos", TheOrdre.getLe_Ordre_1());
         jsonObject.accumulate("LeOrdreTot", TheOrdre.getLe_Ordre_2());


        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();  

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib 
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person); 

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json); 

        // 6. set httpPost Entity 
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();  


        // 10. convert inputstream to string 
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else 
            result = "Did not work!"; 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } 

    // 11. return result
    return result +TheOrdre.getLe_CodeClient()+"__"+TheOrdre.getLe_CodeDest()+"__"+TheOrdre.getLe_NoOrdre()+ "__"+TheOrdre.getLe_Ordre_1()+"--"+TheOrdre.getLe_Ordre_2(); 
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to help without knowing what your HttpAsyncTask is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which versions you are targeting but I am guessing it's because you didn't account for the different threadpoolexecutors that android uses.

Try this:

```
new HttpAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "http://myseite/Service.svc/FA/SaveData");
```

Newer versions of android uses a linear thread pool executor by default. So asynctask are executed one after the other.

I hope I could help.